# Why are the ShellExecuteEx() parameters not working?

Tags: c++, mfc, shellexecute, shellexecuteex

Let say I want the program "C:\MyProgram.exe" to run with parameters that are two variables. The problem that occurs is that MyProgram only receives 2 parameters, while I clearly pass 3 parameters.

My code:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO    ShExecInfo = { 0 };
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShExecInfo.lpFile = T("\"C:\\MyProgram.exe\"");
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = _T("\"\"") _T(" ") + dir + file[i] + _T(" ") + dir + outputfile + _T(".TIFF");
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, 1500);
if(GetExitCodeProcess(ShExecInfo.hProcess, &exitCode)){
    MessageBox(_T("Conversion ") + file[i] + _T(" unsuccesful."), _T("TEST!"), MB_OK);
    succes = 0;
}
```

Because there isn't much info on the internet on variable parameters with ShellExecuteEx, I could not find a proper explanation for this.

Does any of you maybe know how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because your construct yields into a temporary object and the pointer to it (a CString I guess) is stored but the temporary object is already destroyed when you launch the program.

```
auto str = _T("\"\"") _T(" ") + dir + file[i] + _T(" ") + dir + outputfile + _T(".TIFF");
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = str;
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. What does the 'auto' keyword do exactly? Does it determine the datatype for me?

Comment: Yes. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer

Answer (score 0):

Did you check those two parameters that `MyProgram` receives, what values do they have?

The problem is most likely this piece of code:

```
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = _T("\"\"") _T(" ") + dir + file[i] + _T(" ") + dir + outputfile + _T(".TIFF");
```

You didn't say what types `dir` or `file[i]` have, but in general adding C style strings like this (`TCHAR[]` or `TCHAR*` are still C style strings) doesn't concatenate them, if that's what you expect to happen in this case.

Check what `ShExecInfo.lpParameters`contains after that assignment, by displaying it or preferably with the debugger.